# VARCHAR value not being inserted when taken using $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql table, `checkboxsaved`. It has a column named `checked` of type `varchar(45)`.

The possible values for this column are `Check1`, `Check2`, etc.

Next, I am sending a request with jQuery and passing the value as a GET variable. For example:

```
"http://xyz?checkbox=" + checkbox  // checkbox = Check1
```

I retrieve it using `$checkbox = $_GET['checkbox']` in PHP, and then fire the query:

```
$rv = mysql_query("insert into checkboxsaved (checked) values ('$checkbox')");
```

The value does not get inserted. Strangely, when I add a space or other character in front, e.g.

```
$rv = mysql_query("insert into checkboxsaved (checked) values (' $checkbox')"); // space
$rv = mysql_query("insert into checkboxsaved (checked) values ('r$checkbox')");
```

then the value does get inserted. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? According to me,
when the column is `varchar` I should be able to insert something like `Check1`.

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injection. Please learn about securing your SQL queries. Hint: that means using prepared statements and PDO (or MySQLi).

Comment: Do you know what is the value of $checkbox before running the query? You can print it with `var_dump($checkbox)`. Posting the output here would help us help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing some sanitation. You should run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all user inputted values. Also, in your case, you could also run a regex on the value so that it matches `/^Check[0-9]+$/`.

If that doesn't solve your issue (and it probably doesn't), your script likely isn't receiving the data like you think it is.

ie.

```
$checkbox = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['checkbox']);
$sql = "insert into checkboxsaved (checked) values ('$checkbox');";
//echo $sql; // uncomment this to debug
$rv = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: (And don't forget to anchor the regex, too.)

Comment: I tried with mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['checkbox']); and it doesnt work..I am confused as to why when I add a space or character it gets inserted.. does it have to do something with the datatype in Mysql .. which is varchar